# Integrate kendo scheduler to angular 5 application

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-scheduler

I know it's not the right way to do but is it possible to integrate the kendo Scheduler jQuery component into Angular 5 app? Or  is there an alternative component?

Comment: please try mention few codes !

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. [Here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/) is official documentation how to do it.

Currently there is no replacement for scheduler component.